# NodeJS: route parameter at the first slash works but the same one at the second does not

Tags: node.js, express, path, routes

The file `myProject\app.js` code is:

```
app.use('/student', require('./routes/studentsRoutes'));
app.get('/loadexercise', function (req, res) {
    let result = {unit: req.query.unit, part: req.query.part};
    res.json(result);
});
```

The file `myProject\routes\studentsRoutes.js` contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/loadexercise', function (req, res) {
    let result = {unit: req.query.unit, part: req.query.part};
    res.json(result);
});
module.exports = router;
```

When I run the link `http://localhost:55555/loadexercise?unit=1&part=1` from a browser, the render is OK like this: `{"unit":"1","part":"1"}`.

But when I run the link `http://localhost:55555/student/loadexercise?unit=1&part=1`, it shows `[]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This works OK for me. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Seems fine to me. it should work. make sure you are sending the same URL exactly. More that that I would suggest to use a debugger tool so you could see exactly what is going on

Comment: Thank you, ggorden and Dvir. Here is my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rpb5ur4DWdetJLhjz5ZG-2vv_Qhgs7cu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request `http://localhost:55555/student/loadexercise?unit=1&part=1` will fall into the route `/:unit` because it has a parameter and this route goes above the route `/loadexercise` and Express treats `loadexercise` as a value of the `unit` parameter.
You simply need to move all routes with static parts before routes with the same part of a route but as a dynamic parameter:

```js
router.get('/loadexercise', function (req, res) {
    let result = {unit: req.query.unit, part: req.query.part};
    res.json(result);
});
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {});
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {});
router.get('/changepass', function(req, res, next) {});
router.post('/changepass', function(req, res, next) {});
router.get('/:unit', function (req, res) {
...
```